# Problem Posting bigger files to IIS with Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, iis, upload

i submit a simple file via POST Testform to itself on a windows authenticated website running on Win 10 Enterprise/IIS. Everything works fine with IE and FF.

With Chrome the upload works even fine with a file of 8kb. With a file of about 70kb i get a authentication required.

My testform index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="de" lang="de">
<body>
<?php
    echo '<pre>';   
    print_r($_FILES);   
    print "</pre>";
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./index.php" method="POST">    
    Upload File: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 8M
```

If i use anonymous authentication type for the iis-site everything works fine with chrome too. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you use anonymous authentication type for the iis-site, it will works fine with chrome.

This seems to be a problem with chrome.

**Below are some article about the issue.**

[1. Configure Chrome To Allow Windows Authentication Without Prompting](https://knowledge.kofax.com/Smart_Process_Applications_-_TotalAgility/Configuration/Configure_Chrome_To_Allow_Windows_Authentication_Without_Prompting)

[2. Google Chrome and Auto Login Using Windows Authentication](https://www.cherwell.com/community/groups/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=853&MessageKey=c9baecf9-3c7d-4326-b3dd-b1f26c10b41a&CommunityKey=f7af2f80-1055-4f94-a829-5b08429c0b0b&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2Fcommunity%2Fgroups%2Fcommunity-home%2Fdigestviewer%3Ftab%3Ddigestviewer%26CommunityKey%3Df7af2f80-1055-4f94-a829-5b08429c0b0b)

Comment: @Frank Are other browsers normal, right?

Comment: IE, FF & Edge works fine. @Jason i forgot to post that thq fqdn was inside security/intranetzone.